# Truffle Suite with TypeError: soljson.cwrap is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I had trouble in executing *truffle compile* since hoped to communicate with Ethereum using web3.js, for the purpose of translating Contract file(*.sol) into a JSON format that JavaScript can access.

However, I have encountered the issue on the terminal:

**Error: TypeError: soljson.cwrap is not a function
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/legacy/index.js:72:1)**

I would like to remedy this issue since Googling failed to give any realistic solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you compile it via truffle CLI? What is your solc version?

Comment: I used VSCode, Solidity 0.5.10.